# IntelliJ can't import sbt project

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

```
Error while importing sbt project:

d; set _root_.org.jetbrains.sbt.StructureKeys.sbtStructureOptions in Global := "download resolveClassifiers" ;*/*:dumpStructureTo /private/var/folders/5v/g3zxt_7d64g3sd_56bzpqbvh0000gn/T/sbt-structure.xml; session clear-all
[error] Expected ID character
[error] Not a valid command: d
[error] Expected 'debug'
[error] Expected project ID
[error] Expected configuration
[error] Expected ':' (if selecting a configuration)
[error] Expected key
[error] Not a valid key: d
[error] d; set _root_.org.jetbrains.sbt.StructureKeys.sbtStructureOptions in Global := "download resolveClassifiers" ;*/*:dumpStructureTo /private/var/folders/5v/g3zxt_7d64g3sd_56bzpqbvh0000gn/T/sbt-structure.xml; session clear-all
[error]  ^
```

The error appeared after I upgraded the sbt version to `sbt.version=0.13.16` in `./project/build.properties`. Using sbt from the terminal works just fine.

Update: A workaround I found is to disable importing the project via the sbt shell.

Comment: Nobody answer :(

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting the target folder and running the commands again